# How to add android arsenal library to my project?

Tags: android

I am trying to use android arsenal libraries.  i found a library here: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1615 , and i downloaded a .zip file. i want to use it in my project.i have followed the instruction to add the library 
and add this code to the gradle

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.chenupt:SpringIndicator:1.0.2'
}
```

.but it still didn't work well.

How do i add it to my project with Android Studio ?

Comment: what is your mean about "but it still didn't work well." ?

Comment: Sounds like you made a mistake in your gradle file. Can you post your entire build.gradle file as an Edit to your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look what you have added to your gradle dependecies, and what is in a tutorial. And you don't need any zip file, gradle will download the dependecies for you.

It should be like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.chenupt.android:springindicator:1.0.2@aar'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Java [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)  `compile` is deprecated.

> <s>compile</s> (Deprecated)
>
> Compile time dependencies. Superseded by implementation.

It should be like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.chenupt.android:springindicator:1.0.2@aar'
}
```